# FB.event.subscribe('comment.create') doesn't work

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get a notification when an user comments using the social plugin. The code is as following:

```
<fb:comments href='someurl' width='400'></fb:comments>
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response)
{
 alert(response);
}
```

Simple, but it's not working. Someone got some possible errors? From my research online, it seems as if the notification has no real consistency. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: i ran into the same problem. `comment.create` event will not fire unless there are existing comment(s). there's a bug out on this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19827

Comment: I tried all kinds of things to solve this problem.  I added a comment and then deleted so many times I can't even begin to count.  So this time I commented, then reloaded the page.  I then commented again and the event comment.create fired.  Thank you for your "Comment" here, paul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `notify="true"` attribute to the `fb:comments` tag.

```
<fb:comments notify="true" href='someurl' width='400'></fb:comments>
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response)
{
 alert(response);
}
```

Comment: i tried the notify attribute but it didnt work. if its just plain it sometimes does, but for some reason it doesnt in my setup. the like button notification works though

Answer (score 4):

why not to close the function call?

> FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) 
>   {
>     alert(response); 
>   });

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues until I stumbled upon this answer here:

[Methods subscribed via FB.Event.subscribe to comment.create or comment.remove are not triggered](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7386874/methods-subscribed-via-fb-event-subscribe-to-comment-create-or-comment-remove-ar)

> You should put everything related to FB.[...] functions (FB.init,
>   FB.Event.suscribe, ...) in
>
> window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
>       // Your code });
>
> Otherwise your code will be parsed before the FB js sdk has been fully loaded and you will >never really suscribe to
>   your event

That might be obvious to a lot of people but for me and others who are new to this that might trip you up.